# Opengl access violation following tutorial

Tags: visual-c++, opengl, access-violation, glew, glfw

I am currently learning how to use OpenGL for Windows. 
To check if i set up the libraries correctly, i am compiling a set of tutorials that should work.

Right now im following this set:
http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/beginners-tutorials/tutorial-2-the-first-triangle/

The previous tutorial compiled fine, so i was sure i had everything set up correctly, but the second one keeps screwing me over, i cant really find any issue with my setup either.
I am using Visual Express c++ 2010.

## In source-files i have:

main.cpp:

```
// Include standard headers
  #include <stdio.h>
  #include <stdlib.h>

// Include GLEW
#include <GL/glew.h>

// Include GLFW
#include <GL/glfw.h>

// Include GLM
#include <glm/glm.hpp>
using namespace glm;

#include "shader.h"

int main( void )
{
// Initialise GLFW
if( !glfwInit() )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to initialize GLFW\n" );
    return -1;
}

glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_FSAA_SAMPLES, 4);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);

// Open a window and create its OpenGL context
if( !glfwOpenWindow( 1024, 768, 0,0,0,0, 32,0, GLFW_WINDOW ) )
{
    fprintf( stderr, "Failed to open GLFW window. If you have an Intel GPU, they are not 3.3 compatible. Try the 2.1 version of the tutorials.\n" );
    glfwTerminate();
    return -1;
}

// Initialize GLEW
if (glewInit() != GLEW_OK) {
    fprintf(stderr, "Failed to initialize GLEW\n");
    return -1;
}

glfwSetWindowTitle( "Tutorial 02" );

// Ensure we can capture the escape key being pressed below
glfwEnable( GLFW_STICKY_KEYS );

// Dark blue background
glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.3f, 0.0f);

GLuint VertexArrayID;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);
glBindVertexArray(VertexArrayID);

// Create and compile our GLSL program from the shaders
GLuint programID = LoadShaders( "SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader", "SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader" );


static const GLfloat g_vertex_buffer_data[] = { 
    -1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     1.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
     0.0f,  1.0f, 0.0f,
};

GLuint vertexbuffer;
glGenBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(g_vertex_buffer_data), g_vertex_buffer_data, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

do{

    // Clear the screen
    glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );

    // Use our shader
    glUseProgram(programID);

    // 1rst attribute buffer : vertices
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertexbuffer);
    glVertexAttribPointer(
        0,                  // attribute 0. No particular reason for 0, but must match the layout in the shader.
        3,                  // size
        GL_FLOAT,           // type
        GL_FALSE,           // normalized?
        0,                  // stride
        (void*)0            // array buffer offset
    );

    // Draw the triangle !
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3); // From index 0 to 3 -> 1 triangle

    glDisableVertexAttribArray(0);

    // Swap buffers
    glfwSwapBuffers();

} // Check if the ESC key was pressed or the window was closed
while( glfwGetKey( GLFW_KEY_ESC ) != GLFW_PRESS &&
       glfwGetWindowParam( GLFW_OPENED ) );

// Close OpenGL window and terminate GLFW
glfwTerminate();

// Cleanup VBO
glDeleteBuffers(1, &vertexbuffer);
glDeleteVertexArrays(1, &VertexArrayID);

return 0;
}
```

shader.cpp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#include <GL/glew.h>

#include "shader.h"

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path){

// Create the shaders
GLuint VertexShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
GLuint FragmentShaderID = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);

// Read the Vertex Shader code from the file
std::string VertexShaderCode;
std::ifstream VertexShaderStream(vertex_file_path, std::ios::in);
if(VertexShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(VertexShaderStream, Line))
        VertexShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    VertexShaderStream.close();
}

// Read the Fragment Shader code from the file
std::string FragmentShaderCode;
std::ifstream FragmentShaderStream(fragment_file_path, std::ios::in);
if(FragmentShaderStream.is_open()){
    std::string Line = "";
    while(getline(FragmentShaderStream, Line))
        FragmentShaderCode += "\n" + Line;
    FragmentShaderStream.close();
}



GLint Result = GL_FALSE;
int InfoLogLength;



// Compile Vertex Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", vertex_file_path);
char const * VertexSourcePointer = VertexShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(VertexShaderID, 1, &VertexSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(VertexShaderID);

// Check Vertex Shader
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(VertexShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> VertexShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
glGetShaderInfoLog(VertexShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &VertexShaderErrorMessage[0]);




// Compile Fragment Shader
printf("Compiling shader : %s\n", fragment_file_path);
char const * FragmentSourcePointer = FragmentShaderCode.c_str();
glShaderSource(FragmentShaderID, 1, &FragmentSourcePointer , NULL);
glCompileShader(FragmentShaderID);

// Check Fragment Shader
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &Result);
glGetShaderiv(FragmentShaderID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> FragmentShaderErrorMessage(InfoLogLength);
glGetShaderInfoLog(FragmentShaderID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &FragmentShaderErrorMessage[0]);




// Link the program
fprintf(stdout, "Linking program\n");
GLuint ProgramID = glCreateProgram();
glAttachShader(ProgramID, VertexShaderID);
glAttachShader(ProgramID, FragmentShaderID);
glLinkProgram(ProgramID);

// Check the program
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_LINK_STATUS, &Result);
glGetProgramiv(ProgramID, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &InfoLogLength);
std::vector<char> ProgramErrorMessage( max(InfoLogLength, int(1)) );
glGetProgramInfoLog(ProgramID, InfoLogLength, NULL, &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);
fprintf(stdout, "%s\n", &ProgramErrorMessage[0]);


glDeleteShader(VertexShaderID);
glDeleteShader(FragmentShaderID);

return ProgramID;
}
```

## In headers i have:

shader.h:

```
#ifndef SHADER_H
#define SHADER_H

GLuint LoadShaders(const char * vertex_file_path,const char * fragment_file_path);

#endif
```

## In Resource-files i have:

SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader:

```
 #version 330 core

// Ouput data
out vec3 color;

void main()
{

// Output color = red 
color = vec3(1,0,0);

}
```

SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader:

```
 #version 330 core

// Input vertex data, different for all executions of this shader.
layout(location = 0) in vec3 vertexPosition_modelspace;

void main(){

gl_Position.xyz = vertexPosition_modelspace;

}
```

## Debug:

Linker:
kernel32.lib;glu32.lib;glew32.lib;GLFW.lib;openGL32.lib;user32.lib;gdi32.lib;winspool.lib;comdlg32.lib;advapi32.lib;shell32.lib;ole32.lib;oleaut32.lib;uuid.lib;odbc32.lib;odbccp32.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)

And finally, the debug output:

```
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Users\Leif Andreas\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\Spacecraft\Debug\Spacecraft.exe', Symbols loaded.
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntdll.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\kernel32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\KernelBase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glew32.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\opengl32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcrt.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\advapi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sechost.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\rpcrt4.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\sspicli.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cryptbase.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\gdi32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\user32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\lpk.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\usp10.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\glu32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ddraw.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dciman32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\setupapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\cfgmgr32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\oleaut32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ole32.dll', Symbols loaded.
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\devobj.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\dwmapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcp100d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msvcr100d.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\imm32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\msctf.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvinit.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\detoured.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\Nvd3d9wrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\coprocmanager\nvdxgiwrap.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\uxtheme.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\winmm.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\nvoglv32.dll', Cannot find or open the PDB file
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shell32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\shlwapi.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\version.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\ntmarta.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\Wldap32.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x690) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'Spacecraft.exe': Loaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll', Symbols loaded (source information stripped).
'Spacecraft.exe': Unloaded 'C:\Windows\SysWOW64\powrprof.dll'
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1e7c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread 'Win32 Thread' (0x1f38) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
First-chance exception at 0x00000000 in Spacecraft.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
Unhandled exception at 0x76fb15de (ntdll.dll) in Spacecraft.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.
The program '[7988] Spacecraft.exe: Native' has exited with code -1073741819 (0xc0000005).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://www.opengl-tutorial.org/miscellaneous/faq/#header-3

And from tutorial 1 :

> You can also launch any tutorial from inside Visual Studio, but you
>   will need to setup the Working Directory first : right-click on
>   Playground, choose Debugging, Working Directory, Browse, and navigate
>   to C:\Users\XYZ\Projects\OpenGLTutorials\playground. Validate.
>   Right-click on Playground once again, “Choose as startup project”. You
>   can now debug the code by pressing F5.

[image]

I just modified the tutorial because so many people get stuck at this.

What's more, if you use the standard version of GLEW instead of the one that is bundled with the tutorial, you won't be able to use the Core Profile because of a GLEW bug. Use

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_COMPAT_PROFILE);
```

instead of

```
glfwOpenWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: Who saif I would be posting only the link ^^

Comment: I did't write the previous comment. It was probably inserted automatically from the Review Task system. At the moment of my review, the only thing i saw was the link, so i marked the answer to be deleted as "link only"

Comment: Thanks, i will try this out tomorrow! Just caught a fever and im getting a little too dizzy to code properly at the moment!

Comment: Ok, got that part working, but to really learn this stuff i need to be able to write projects from the ground up, and that is why i am trying to put tutorial2 into a separate project. I have everything set up like in the original post, but it returns a access violation, and i got no idea why, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Probably the same problem : the shader loader can't find SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader and SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader. If unsure, debug ! That's what Visual is made for. Use the F5 key.

Comment: I have debugged, i dont really know what more to do, tried to get this working since Thursday. I have tried putting SimpleVertexShader.vertexshader and SimpleFragmentShader.fragmentshader in the project root, and in the visuals resource-files, but right now im out of ideas, i have pretty much tried everything.. I dont know if its my code or my libraries that are messing up.

Comment: Your code is fine, since it's actually mine. Your project compiled and linked fine, so this is good too. I'm 99% sure it's a dumb directories problem. When you run your .exe by double-clicking on it from the explorer, does it work ?

Comment: It's crashing when i run it from the explorer yeah! A possibility i havent tested yet could be that the projects are saved in a directory that has a path with a whitespace in it, that used to be a problem when writing native apps for android, but idk if that is a problem with visual? If so, how do i move where projects are created via visual? Thanks for answers!

Comment: Send your project to the website's contact mail, I'll have a quick look

Comment: Thanks,i really appreciate the help! i will do it tomorrow, gotta get some sleep now, apparently im not supposed to code while being sick. :p